# $scope is never updated - Angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the $ scope.parents variable that is located in the controller "userCrtl". The problem is that its value is not being updated after the AJAX call. I tried to use $ q to apply the changes after the end of the promise; However, I did not succeed. I tried to use $ scope.watch to detect changes, but this method is never started. As a result, my html page is never updated. When I use console.log ($ scope.parents) the value of $ scope.parents is displayed normally, but the html view is not updated. If $ scope.parents is initialized with a default value ($ scope.parents = "test"), this value is displayed but is not changed any more.
The most frustrating thing is that I do the same thing in other application controllers and everything works fine. Something is causing only previously defined values ​​for $ scope variables to be displayed in html.
The following is the controller code:

```
app.controller("userCtrl", function($scope, userService, $http) {
    $scope.panels = userService.get();
    $scope.parents = null;
  $scope.start = function(panel) {
       // Get parents blocks
        $http.get(path + "getpaneluser /" + panel.painelUsername).then (function (response) {
            $scope.parents = response.data;
         // Here the value of parents is normally displayed
                  console.log($scope.parents);
        }, function(error) {
        });
    };
// Displays only null, even if $scope.parents has a value after the AJAX call
  $scope.$Watch('parents', function () {
        console.log($scope.parents);
     });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-right: 0%;">
 {{parents}} <!-- value never displayed -->
    <div ng-repeat="item in parents" class="declareContainer">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you all for your help

Comment: You have a typo in your code : $scope.$Watch should be $scope.$watch  but this is not the reason of your problem

Comment: Just to cover all the bases, can you confirm that the html template you provided is within the userCtrl and not under the purview of a different controller? That would explain why the UI continues to show the old values rather then the new values loaded by the userCtrl since the $scope.parents set by the userCtrl will be within its own child scope and not available to your html template.

Comment: So friend, in the app.js inside the routing define the following:
 
templateUrl: 'views/panelUser.html',
 controller: 'userCtrl'

I belive that is right

Answer (score 2):

After your ajax call scope.$apply the data in the scope

```
 $http.get(path + "getpaneluser /" + panel.painelUsername).then (function (response) {
            $scope.parents = response.data;
         // Here the value of parents is normally displayed
                  console.log($scope.parents);
  $scope.$apply()
        }, function(error) {
        });
```

Comment: Actually, the then() call is applied in the digest cycle, so you have to use $scope.$apply() to apply your change on $scope.parents

Comment: My friend, the problem continues ... I do not know what to try anymore. Can I get the value of $ scope.parents only in the back end through console.log ($ scope.parents). In my routing, I set the html template and controller for each route.
The fact is that if $ scope.parents is initialized with some value, I can display that value on the html page. If the value of the variable is changed, the html remains static.

Comment: I think it would be best to make a video demonstrating what is happening to make it easier to understand my problem.

Comment: My problem is only solved using $ rootScope. I did not want to do it, but that's what worked.
As commented out, the local $ scope of controller userCtrl is never updated, already using $ rootScope this is solved.